# Update in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I made SP in SQL Server for update. The SP is create successfully but It shows error at execution. Below is SP and execution. Please help me with it.

```
alter procedure updaterecored(@studentsrid int,
@sfirstname varchar(50), @slastname varchar(20), @semail varchar(50))
as 
begin   
update tbl_Students set Firstname = @sfirstname, lastname=@slastname, email=@semail
where studentid=@studentsrid
end
```

then for execution

```
 exec updaterecored(4, 'dipika', 'Sharma', 'ds@gmail.com')
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Never post 'I get an error' without posting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing the procedure don't use braces. Use this

```
 exec updaterecored 4,'dipika','Sharma','ds@gmail.com'
```

Comment: @Bha15 Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Note also that if you had quoted what the error was while mentioning it, two other people would not have wasted their time writing answers speculating about different causes.

Comment: Yes, that did it, as you can see from the green tick shown below the voting controls.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in your update statement dont match the ones that you pass through. @SEmail  and @semail are different values. Change your update statement in your SP to

```
update tbl_Students set Firstname = @sfirstname, lastname=@SLastname ,email=@SEmail 
where studentid=@studentsrid
```

Edit:
Also check your column names Firstname has a capital but lastname doesn't, is it like that in your table?

Comment: Unless OP specifically chose a case-sensitive collation, column names aren't case-sensitive, so that wouldnt matter.

Comment: True, but judging on the stored procedure and the fact its not working i would guess that the collation is set to a case sensitive one.

Comment: I don't think it will matter as it is not case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

here issues you have    @semail and @SEmail are two different Variable. I have changed the code below.Now it should work.

```
 alter procedure updaterecored(@studentsrid int,
    @sfirstname varchar(50),@SLastname varchar(20),@SEmail varchar(50))
    as 
    begin   
    update tbl_Students set Firstname = @sfirstname, lastname=@slastname,email=@SEmail
    where studentid=@studentsrid
    end


-- exec updaterecored 4,'dipika','Sharma','ds@gmail.com'
```

Comment: `Declare @TemP int = 12; Select @teMp; ` Do you get error ? :)

Comment: In which line of stored procedure @PrabhatG

Comment: Just run it separately. Point is, variables are not case sensitive unless specified explicitly

Comment: it depends upon server configuration to be case sensitive or not @PrabhatG

Comment: Yes, but I wager that most servers are not set to a case-sensitive collation. This is the problem with the OP never bothering to specify what error they got: everyone is just blindly guessing, and trying to reason about why their own guess could be the right one.

Comment: @rohitPoudel There wasn't issue with code. Issue was when I tried to execute it. Thanks to Madhivanan. Issue is solved